# unable to load local JSON file

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load JSON locally but it give me error of file not found (404). I have tried following

- renaming the json file
- trimming down JSON to see if there was a error there

Following is my folder structure and my JSON
[image: file structure]

```js
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Lorem, ipsum.",
        "image": "./src/assets/1.jpg",
        "desc": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam, neque."
    }
```

Error
[image: error]

Comment: What tool is this? Where is the code running? Are you wanting to run this in a web-browser, a local console, or `nodejs`?

Comment: Look in the network tab and click response  - it is likely an HTML 404 file  try removing the `./` you have some weird chars in front of that anyway

Comment: why do you have `\`>` in front of the file name?

Comment: @Craicerjack which file. all file egg end with a ext name

Comment: @mplungjan I tried removing it. the error is the same.

Comment: Please post code instead of pictures of code. Also look in the network tab to see if the path reflects reality

Comment: @localhost the file you are trying to load. `fetch("\`>./local_data.json")`

Answer (score 0):

Relative URLs, in client-side JavaScript, are resolved relative to the URL of the HTML document the script is running in.

They are **not** resolved relative to the URL of the JS file.

Your JSON file is in the same directory as the JS file, but the URL you are asking for is looking for it in the same directory as the HTML file… which is one level up.